# How to display a button for each row in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL database of booking records and I am displaying this in an HTML table. I was wondering how to add a button in every row of the table that will allow me to delete that row from the database.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <h2> All bookings </h2> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <table class='striped white'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Surname</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
                if($result->num_rows>0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo 
                        "<tr>".
                        "<td>". $row['id'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['firstName'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['surName'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['date'] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>". $row['timeSlot'] . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo 'no bookings';
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a cell with a URL that has code configured to run a `DELETE` command in your database. This is typically what atomic ID's are used for. Lets assume the above table is in a file called `table.php`. Given this, we can adjust your first table cell to the following:

```
...
"<td>". $row['id'] . "<br /><a href=\"table.php?deleteId={$row['id']}\">Delete Row</a></td>" .
...
```

Now when you click this link you'll have a GET variable assigned in the `$_GET` superglobal array called "deleteId" that you can use to delete the row.

You'll want to place this *above* your table so that any deletions reflect in the table each time you reload the page.

```
if (isset($_GET['deleteId'])) {
  // Sanitize input for SQL injection risk
  $deleteId = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['deleteId'])

  if (!is_null($deleteId)) {
    // Just an example, you will need to correct this query and optionally use parameters vs. directly putting the variable in the SQL string
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM ... WHERE id = '$deleteId'");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this does work but I've just realized that this program also doesn't display the first record in the database for some reason (the HTML table starts at ID = 2). Also is there anyway I can use modals to write a confirm message for the deletion? I have Javascript and I'm using Materialize CSS

Comment: Sure -- you could use `confirm` dialog in JavaScript -- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp (no need for extra modal stuff) -- basically use <a href="..." onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">...</a> if you want! If I answered your original question above do you mind marking it as your correct answer?

Comment: Thank you! I have marked it as the answer. Was also wondering why it doesn't display the first record in the database for some reason (the HTML table starts at ID = 2)? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bedlams suggestions seems like a good solution.
However I would recommend to NOT delete anything from your database. I would add a column to my table 'Removed' with an integer 0 or 1.
1 = deleted
0 = not deleted (default)

When clicking the button in the table it updates the selected row's `removed` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap so this example uses that library.

If you want to add a confirmation modal, just simply replace bedlam's a href to something like:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#whateveridyougiveyourmodal" data-id="$row['id']">Delete Row</a>
```

Then add a button in that modal that will handle the deletion logic. You can use bedlam's a href in that modal.

```
<button type="button" id="delete">Delete</button>
```

You'll need to add some javascript to get the dynamic modal. Something like:

```
$("#whateveridyougiveyourmodal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(event){
    var id = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $(this).find("#id-hidden-input").val(id);
});

$("#delete").click(function(event){
    var id = document.querySelector("input[name='id']").value;
    // POST ID TO DELETE FOR EXAMPLE I'LL USE AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:{data: id},
        url: "WHERE YOU WANT TO HANDLE DELETION LOGIC.php",
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

In your "WHERE YOU WANT TO HANDLE DELETION LOGIC.php" you'll want to accept the POST data with the super global "$_POST", or in this case "$_POST['data']".